# ffmpeg - infinite loop when adding watermark

Tags: ffmpeg

Arguments:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -loop 1 -i banner.png -c:a copy -filter_complex "[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=30:d=0.5[watermark]; [0:v][watermark]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h" out.mp4
```

Output:

```
frame=  131 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=     110kB time=00:00:05.38 bitrate= 167.9kbits/
...
Past duration 0.999992 too large
frame= 3131 fps=258 q=28.0 size=    2112kB time=00:02:05.17 bitrate= 138.2kbits/
frame= 3131 fps=248 q=28.0 size=    2112kB time=00:02:05.17 bitrate= 138.2kbits/
...
```

Then it loops infinitely. I used [this](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-May/026700.html) as an example and just modified the overlay. out.mp4 does contain the expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `shortest`. As you are dealing with multiple streams you need to tell when the whole process need to be finished.

> **-shortest (output)**
>
> Finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends.

Your watermark image loops infinitely with `-loop`. So you need to specify when to finish this loop. Following will work for you.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -loop 1 -i input_image -c:a copy -filter_complex "
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=30:d=0.5[watermark];
[0:v][watermark]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1" out_video
```

As you use `filter_complex` you need to use `shortest` with the filter. Also you may need to resize the image and you can use [`scale`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#scale-1) filter for it.

**UPDATE**

To scale the video you can use the `scale` filter and chain it with the faded watermark you have used. Following will scale the input video to 1280x720 and you can find more scaling options [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling%20%28resizing%29%20with%20ffmpeg).

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -loop 1 -i input_image -c:a copy -filter_complex "
[0:v]scale=1280:720[scaled];
[1:v]fade=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=out:st=30:d=0.5[watermark];
[scaled][watermark]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1" out_video
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Where should I place scale to resize the input video instead of the watermark?

Comment: @awalmartbag answer updated with the scale filter usage.